# How to pass a database data instead of array in the controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-controller

In my controller in finorfail it returns array but instead i want pass package name
My controller:

```
    public function package($package){
        $package = Packages::findOrFail($package);
        return view('pages.package',[
            'package' => $package,
        ]);
    }
```

My we.php:

```
Route::prefix('/packages')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', 'PackageController@packages')->name('package.show');
    Route::get('/{package}', 'PackageController@package')->name('package.show');
});
```

My Model:

```
class Packages extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'packages';

    protected $fillable = ['Package_Banner_Image','Package_Image','Package_Type','Package_Name','Package_Short_Description','Package_Price','Package_Duration','Package_Level','Package_Location'];
}
```

SO i want to pass PackageName instead of array of numbers
[image]
So instead of 1 i want it to be package name in the url

My Migration:

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->string('slug')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('meta_title')->nullable();
            $table->text('meta_description')->nullable();
            $table->integer('main')->nullable();
            $table->string('publish')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: There is  a misspelled `'Package_Short_Description',','Package_Price'` would be `'Package_Short_Description','Package_Price'`

Comment: @sta i was taking out some of the migration data unnecessary for this question so now how can i pass package_name instead of array in the url and i fixed that in the question

Comment: you should give correct syntax, before asking a question. If anyone try with that code, they may face unexcepted error. Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @sta yeah i am sorry for that and i fixed the syntax

Comment: Read documents : https://laravel.com/docs/master/responses#redirecting-named-routes @NutanPanta

Comment: You want to return `package_name` only?  Then pass it like that, change code as `return view('pages.package',[
            'package' => $package->Package_Name
        ]);` access `Package_Name` from blade as `{{ $package }}`

Comment: @sta can you look in the picture above i just edited i do need it in the view i need in my url

Comment: If you want name, then your will be like this `Packages::where('Package_name', $package)->first();`

Comment: If returns empty object, return a 404 `$package = Packages::where('Package_name', $package)->first(); if(empty($package)) { return abort(404)} ;`

Comment: @sta it worked now is there a way to put the package name in kebab case in url

Comment: Use **STR Slug Method**, to make your url pretty and SEO friendly, 
Use it while insert url to table, make  an another field for store slug url, 
And one foe name (not slug) https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-str-slug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
public function package($package)
{
   $package = Packages::where('Package_name', $package)->first();
  
    if(empty($package)) { 
      return abort(404); // if $package is empty, it will return 404
    } 

    return view('pages.package',[
         'package' => $package,
    ]);
}
```

The **Str::slug** method generates a URL friendly `"slug"` from the given string, so while saving `Package_name` make an another fileld called slug, where the slug name will be saved  :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$slug = Str::slug('welcome to stackoverflow', '-');

// welcome-to-stackoverflow
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219452/discussion-on-answer-by-sta-how-to-pass-a-database-data-instead-of-array-in-the).